# Java NullPointerException Collision is the source, but not sure Why

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, tiles, pixel, slick2d

I have tried running the code without the collision, and it works fine. But with it, I get a NullPointerException. The root of the problem has something to do with

```
blocked[xAxis][yAxis] = true;
```

edit: Sorry for not providing the traces earlier.

console:

```
Wed Dec 21 20:32:52 PST 2011 INFO:Slick Build #274
Wed Dec 21 20:32:52 PST 2011 INFO:LWJGL Version: 2.8.2
Wed Dec 21 20:32:52 PST 2011 INFO:OriginalDisplayMode: 1440 x 900 x 32 @60Hz
Wed Dec 21 20:32:52 PST 2011 INFO:TargetDisplayMode: 800 x 600 x 0 @0Hz
Wed Dec 21 20:32:53 PST 2011 INFO:Starting display 800x600
Wed Dec 21 20:32:53 PST 2011 INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true
Loading: net.java.games.input.DirectAndRawInputEnvironmentPlugin
Wed Dec 21 20:32:54 PST 2011 INFO:Found 0 controllers
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at RPG.Main.init(Main.java:41)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:390)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:314)
at RPG.Main.main(Main.java:102)
```

Properties of the TiledMap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map SYSTEM "http://mapeditor.org/dtd/1.0/map.dtd">
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="10" height="10" tilewidth="32"                   <tileheight="32">
<tileset name="wall" firstgid="1" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
<image source="wall.png"/>
<tile id="0">
<properties>
<property name="blocked" value="true"/>
</properties>
</tile>
</tileset>
<tileset name="grass" firstgid="2" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
<image source="grass.png"/>
</tileset>
<layer name="Layer 0" width="10" height="10">
<data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
H4sIAAAAAAAAAGNkYGBgJBIzEcCUqBvsYtTwLzEYAHHwHBmQAQAA
</data>
</layer>
</map>
```

full code.

```
public class Main extends BasicGame {

Image player = null;
Image land = null;

private float playerX = 32f;
private float playerY = 32f;
private static final int SIZE = 32;

private boolean[][] blocked;

private TiledMap map;


public Main()
{
    super("Classic");
}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc)
        throws SlickException 
{
    player = new Image("RPG/player.png");
    map = new TiledMap("RPG/Map.tmx");

    for (int xAxis=0;xAxis<map.getWidth(); xAxis++)
    {
         for (int yAxis=0;yAxis<map.getHeight(); yAxis++)
         {
             int tileID = map.getTileId(xAxis, yAxis, 0);
             String value = map.getTileProperty(tileID, "blocked", "false");
             if ("true".equals(value))
             {
                 blocked[xAxis][yAxis] = true;
             }
         }
     }

}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta)
        throws SlickException
{
    Input input = gc.getInput();

    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)) {
        if (!isBlocked(playerX, playerY - delta * 0.1f))
        {
        playerX-= delta * 0.1f;
        }
    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)) {
        if (!isBlocked(playerX, playerY - delta * 0.1f))
        {
        playerX+= delta * 0.1f;
        }
    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
        if (!isBlocked(playerX, playerY - delta * 0.1f))
        {
        playerY-= delta * 0.1f;
        }
    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) {
        if (!isBlocked(playerX, playerY - delta * 0.1f))
        {
        playerY+= delta * 0.1f;
        }
    }

}

public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g)
        throws SlickException
{
    map.render(0, 0);

    player.draw(playerX, playerY);

}

private boolean isBlocked(float playerX, float playerY)
{
    int xBlock = (int)playerX / SIZE;
    int yBlock = (int)playerY / SIZE;
    return blocked[xBlock][yBlock];
}

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws SlickException
{
     AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer( new Main() );
     app.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
     app.start();
   }

}
```

Comment: Please post a full stack trace with line numbers (and mention what line that is in your code)

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: NPEs are usually pretty easy to debug. The stack trace will tell you what line it was thrown from. All you need to do is stick a breakpoint there, and see what null variable you're trying to dereference. You've provided no information about where the NPE is thrown, so what are we supposed to tell you?

Comment: Comments in the code wouldn't hurt anyone (especially you).  Where is the "collision" code that supposedly produces the error.  And, for that matter, where is your stack trace??

Comment: sorry. posted the trace.

Comment: Please provide more information then `i don't know why`, and shorten your program. No one will want to spent time to read whole post in blog in order to run your program and find out the problem you're trying to ask.

Comment: I apologize. I took out the "i don't know why", and explained what was the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`blocked` is never created. You need to say somewhere:

```
blocked = new boolean[xsize][ysize];
```

where xsize and ysize are set appropriately.

Because you haven't done this, `blocked` is `null` instead of an array. That's why you're getting the exception when you try to assign something to an element in the array.

In your case, you could add

```
blocked = new boolean[map.getWidth()][map.getHeight()];
```

to the top of your `init()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the array

```
private boolean[][] blocked;
```

that's why you got a `NullPointerException` in `blocked[xAxis][yAxis] = true;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the blocked 2D array initialized anywhere, you need to init it to the size of the map